# Choose function returns negative values if n >= 13

Tags: python, numpy, binomial-coefficients, ncr

I'm trying to compute and display some rows of Pascal's Triangle in Python, using Numpy. I have this code:

```
#Calculates the binomial coefficient from given values
def binomial(n,k):
    #n = int(input("Please input an integer value for n: "))
    #k = int(input("Please input an integer value for k: "))
    factorial = np.ones([1,3],int)
    for a in range(1,n+1):
        factorial[:,0] *=a
    for b in range(1,k+1):
        factorial[:,1] *=b
    for c in range(1,(n-k+1)):
        factorial[:,2] *=c
    solution = int(factorial[:,0]//(factorial[:,1]*factorial[:,2]))
    #print(solution)
    return solution

#Prints Pascal's triangle
def part_b():
    print(1)
    rows = 13  #desired numer of rows
    for n in range(1,rows+1): #iterate for each desired line
        line = [1]
        for k in range(1,n+1): #iterate for position on line
            solution = binomial(n,k)
            line.append(solution)
        print(*line, sep=" ")    
    return
```

Starting from the 13th row, the result is clearly incorrect. It may even include negative numbers, which makes no sense as the code only multiplies and divides positive integers.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you seen a warning saying: `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar multiply`

Comment: No, it does not give me any errors. It just begins calculating the wrong thing, for whatever reason.

Comment: It's a warning not error.

Comment: I dont think Im seeing any warning either. We're doing all of this in Spyder, and from that perspective it all seems to be running normally.

Comment: May I ask if you are executing this as a Python2 program or a Python3 program?  Also, what OS are you running this on?  FYI, when I copied and ran your code (with and import of numpy), on my Linux platform, it ran correctly for 13 rows.  It agreed with a Pascal triangle program I have.

Comment: @NoDakker It has nothing to do with the operating system or the Python version. It has everything to do with the *hardware platform*. 32-bit builds of Python (with a compatible Numpy that uses 32-bit integers by default) will behave as described. 64-bit builds will require at least 21 rows to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ah yes.  Mine is a 64-bit platform.  Always can learn something new.  Thanks @Karl Knechtel.

Comment: Hi @Maren and welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is caused by *integer overflow*, which happens when using Numpy like this - the purpose of Numpy is to give access to the "raw" number-crunching facilities of the computer, which use fixed-size chunks of memory to represent numbers - therefore, they can't represent numbers big enough for your algorithm. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: As it happens, you can get up to 20 rows as required for your assignment, by simply specifying 64-bit integers (this is possible even on a 32-bit build of Python). However, there are also better ways to compute Pascal's Triangle that won't require such large numbers in the first place (i.e., it is not necessary to compute the factorial, which is much larger than any of the numbers in the current row, and then divide it). I strongly recommend [reading the Wikipedia article on Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: In order to ask better questions in the future, please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), take the [tour], and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. We don't want questions to say anything about you, your level of skill, your [deadlines](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) etc.; and we [will edit these things out](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/) of questions. Questions are supposed to be about **the question**, and should be concrete - [not vague requests for help](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, integers are unbounded. It means you can have integers as big as your memory can handle.

However, Numpy is written in C, and is designed to use C's integer types for calculations. In C, there is a limit on the value of integers. Results that exceed that value cause [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

In particular, 13! (the factorial of 13) does not fit in a 32-bit C integer, so the calculation performed by Numpy will overflow.

To avoid the problem, simply don't use Numpy for the calculation.

Comment: *"But it will work"* - Um, aren't we here because it doesn't?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I knew it had to be something like that!! I will see what I can do to fix it. I realy appreciate the help!

Comment: @KellyBundy I think there is language barrier. I apologies for that. By last sentence I meant "If you don't use `numpy` it will work."

Comment: Ah, I get it now. The problem is the *"It will make your code slower"*, because that seems to be talking about **using** numpy, not about **not** using numpy. So the whole thing reads like *"Don't use numpy. Using numpy will make your code slower but it will work."*  Really strange.

Comment: @KellyBundy nah: "Don't use numpy. Not using numpy will make your code slower but it will work."

Comment: But... Their code takes me about 5 ms to run, and if I **don't** use numpy (using `factorial = [1] * 3` and adjusting the rest), it only takes about 0.2 ms to run. That's much **faster**. Not slower.

Comment: Then you'll need to use loops to calculate `factorial[:,0] *=a` and `solution = int(factorial[:,0]//(factorial[:,1]*factorial[:,2]))`. Please notice when I say "slower" I did not test the code. In theory loops in python are slower than c.

Comment: Why would I need loops?

Comment: Well multiplying the 0th column of a numpy array by a number will multiply individual element by the number. But a python list will repeat the list number times. The implementation of `__mul__` are different  for `numpy.ndarray`s and `list`s.

Comment: But it's only one row. I highly doubt that without numpy, they'd repeat that sillyness of making it 2D and would write  extra loops. But ok, I even did *that* now. Still only takes 0.3 ms, still much faster than with numpy.

Comment: Ok :-). For clarity, [this](https://dpaste.org/kunZK) is what my version looks like (the `binomial_no_numpy` function). The point is that their numpy operations really only operate on single numbers. Pointlessly embedded in a 2D array. Highly wasteful. Not at all what numpy is good at. Slower than the pure-Python equivalent. Ok, with a large enough triangle, *eventually* the no-numpy version probably *would* get slower, due to using correct large and thus slower numbers. But for 200 instead of 13 triangle rows, I still get 15 seconds with numpy and 0.9 seconds without.

Comment: Most of the answer was irrelevant, inaccurate (13! doesn't fit either; integers in C can have varying sizes; even specifically the `int` type will have a size that depends on the platform) or noisy. I edited to fix those problems, but this is still not really a good answer. It doesn't cover how to choose a 64-bit integer type (which incidentally would suffice for OP's needs) and doesn't explain *how* to "not use" Numpy. But most importantly, the question is a duplicate and the problem is better explained by the existing Q&A.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *"simply don't use Numpy"* - Though from their current code, I'd say the *simplest* fix is to change `np.ones([1,3],int)` to `np.ones([1,3],object)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was trying to reflect the advice originally given. If the question weren't a duplicate and I were writing the answer myself, I could say something like that, or, you know, mention `np.int64`. But while I'm willing to correct apparent typos and factual errors, I'm not about to replace or supplement bad or suboptimal ideas.

Comment: Not all answers include the solution. Some times you need to let people figure out what they need to do. Give them a clue and they will find the solution. The OP already mentioned that they will find the solution. I don't see why this whole drama. And BTW, the question's reason might be related to what you see as duplication. But it's not apparent at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggested, you could use Python numbers instead of NumPy numbers. You can additionally optimize your code by canceling out some of the factorials beforehand.

Note that `n! / (k! * (n-k)!)` can also be represented as `(n! / k!) / (n-k)!`, so you could reduce `(n! / k!)` to `n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... (k+1)`. Moreover, if `n-k > k` you can perform this substitution using `n-k` instead of `k`, essentially swapping the factorials, making it `(n! / (n-k)!) / k!`.

```py
#Calculates the binomial coefficient from given values
def binomial(n,k):

    # determines the bigger value to use for k! or (n-k)!
    target_k = max(n-k, k)

    reduced_n_fac = 1
    for i in range(target_k+1, n+1):
        reduced_n_fac *= i

    other_fac = 1
    for i in range(1,(n-target_k+1)):
        other_fac *= i
    return reduced_n_fac // other_fac
```

This both removes the negative outputs and makes the code faster to make up for the lack of NumPy.